# Problem to parsing pictures from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, base64

HY!!

I have a webservice that returns a json object with a decodes image

Link to JSON:

[JSON OBJECT](http://surfkid.redio.de/getChannelImage?session_id=ac9892e83e10994b7de728e44450808e&channel_id=1)

My Java Code:

```
String im = json.getChannelImage();
                        if (!im.equals(null))
                        {
                            byte[] decodedString = Base64Coder.decode(im);
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
                            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    }
```

Error:

```
ERROR/Error(285): Length of Base64 encoded input string is not a multiple of 4.
```

I use a libary called Base64Coder, because i want to have the api level 3

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a carriage return and line feed at the end of the image data.  Remove it and it'll probably fix your problem.